# SQL Job not running some of the stored procedures after upgrading from SQL Server 2005 to 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, migration

We recently upgraded from MSSQL 2005 to MSSQL 2008 and after doing so, we are having an issue, 4 out of 10 procedures that we have set up to output XML files aren't working. We never had a problem till we upgraded and the other 6 are running fine.

If we run the job manually, we get the following error for the 4 procedures:

> User name not provided, either use -U to provide the user name or use -T for Trusted Connection

I'm assuming we might have some sort of a permission issue from the new install but not sure where to start.

Comment: Is SQL Agent still using the same account?

Comment: There's not much to go on for this problem, but I must say...that error message is pretty revealing!  It should mean something to you based on your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, yes we are still using the same account. The other procedures are running without issue, using the same connection.